# Can Bhattacharyya distance be greater than one?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I have two vectors, say $P$ and $Q$. I want to find the statistical overlap between two given that $P$ is my reference which I have modeled after Normal distribution and I have parameters for it. $Q$ is the distribution whose overlap with $P$ I want to find.

For this problem, I took two vectors ($P$ with 8000 elements and $Q$ with 60 elements). $P$ will always remain fixed whereas $Q$ will keep on changing. Now, I find Bhattacharyya distance between two to find its statistical overlap. The formula I have used to find distance is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance). Also the previous [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance) suggests that Bhattacharyya distance is always between 0 and 1. I am getting it to be 4.0978. Am I doing something wrong? I am sure my implementation of formula is correct.

Also, is this the best method to solve the problem I have described?

P.S. To include specific numbers so that anybody will be able to replicate my results and tell me what is wrong. Notations are according to the formula described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhattacharyya_distance):

$\sigma_p = 0.0524$

$\sigma_q = 0.0623$

$\mu_p = 0.9244$

$\mu_q = 0.5952$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your vector elements must be between 0 and 1 and sum up to 1 (this is what the Wikipedia link you share means, when it says P and Q are probability distributions)

Answer (score 2):

You're indeed calculating the Bhattacharyya distance (BD), but it is not limited to the [0,1] interval. What you need in this case is the Bhattacharyya coefficient (BC), also in the wikipedia link. It says that BD = -ln(BC), thus, BC = 1 / exp(BD), which lies between 0 and 1.